# SFML shape rotates infinitely

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, sfml, shapes

I'm making a robot arm which moves around a graph but when I try to rotate a shape with my keyboard it rotates infinetly: I want it to rotate just one time when I press the right arrow. How can I solve this?

```
Transform transform;    
while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();

    }
    if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        switch (event.key.code)
        {
        case Keyboard::Right:
            ang += 1;
        }
    }

    window.clear(Color::White);
    window.draw(braccio, transform);
    transform.rotate(ang, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
    window.draw(assi);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: Most of that code should be moved to the `while (window.pollEvent(event))` loop, so it's executed only when the window receives an event.

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: intialize `ang` to 0. Move `transform.rotate(ang, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);` to just after `ang += 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, this line

```
transform.rotate(ang, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
```

Is called on every frame of your program because it's in the main loop, that runs *constantly*. If you want it to happen only while your game detects some input, put it inside your event polling, like so:

```
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    // Do your event handling in here, input, etc.

    if (event.type == Event::Closed)
        window.close();

    // This event case should also be inside here.
    if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        switch (event.key.code)
        {
            case Keyboard::Right:
                transform.rotate(ang, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2); 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise your arm will continue to rotate indefinitely.

EDIT: Thanks @alseether for pointing out that the `Transform::rotate` function adds the angle to the shape's current rotation. So incrementing `ang` each time will gradually make the shape rotate faster and faster... If you don't want this to happen just set `ang` to a constant value and it will rotate the cube at a constant rate.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, [`sf::Transformable::rotate()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#af8a5ffddc0d93f238fee3bf8efe1ebda) adds the angle to the current rotation of the object. If the idea is to rotate the shape a certain angle each time a keyboard key is pressed, you shouldn't increase `ang`. If you do so, the angle will increase more and more each time the key is pressed, wich cause the shape to rotate faster and faster.

Comment: I mean, [`sf::Transform::rotate`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transform.php#af0b7cc3fed36d0fa22d5d331a779eee2), but it's the same idea.